# Probability of random variable - set may not be in event space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

According to [2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210910192655/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition), given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a random variable $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, the probability that $X$ takes on a value in $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$P(X \in S) := P \left( \{ \omega \in \Omega \ : X(\omega) \in S \} \right)$$
How do we know that the event space $\mathcal{F}$ contains $\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in S \}$?

If $\Omega$ is countable, then $\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in S \}$ is a countable union of sets $\{ \omega \}$ and therefore in $\mathcal{F}$. But what if there are uncountably many $\omega$ such that $X(\omega) \in S$? The event space is only closed under countable union...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provide says $X$ is a *measurable* function from $\Omega \to E$. The measurability assumption exactly asserts that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in S\} \in \mathcal F$ for all measurable $S \subset \mathbb R$. So we don't know it so much as assume it in the definition of a random variable.

Comment: I assume $\mathcal{S}$ is the event space $\mathcal{F}$. What is the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra on $E = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @jskattt797 Yep, corrected the typo. Unless stated otherwise, the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ is almost always the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.